# My Xbox 360-to-Home Network connection keeps failing

Tags: xbox-360, networking

My Xbox 360-to-Home Network connection keeps failing. I've reset the network settings to factory defaults numerous times, I've set my IP and DNS Settings from Automatic to Manual and vice-versa, and all my other devices (PC, PS4, Xbox One, PS3, Apple TV, Roku, phone) are working perfectly on my Home Network and have never had any issues. Please help me troubleshoot my Xbox 360-to-Home Network connection.[image]

Comment: I would guess since the Xbox 360 is starting to be pretty old, the router might be using a Wifi encoding that is not supported by the 360 systems. But I do not know anything about wifi so its hard for me to say for sure. Any possibility you could wire it in? I'm gonna assume you already checked, but it could also be a wrong password for the router.

Comment: Yeah I know I have the correct password for the router. ;) I can't really wire it because my router is in the laundry room because my ISP told me to keep it in there because it covers my whole place better. My 360 is in my living room.

Comment: And your phone/other things right next to it got good signal? Like full bars?

Comment: Is this one of the O.G. Xbox 360s where wireless wasn't built in (it uses an [external adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhbLd.png))? If so, perhaps check that.

Comment: Oh yeah, true! There was a model of xbox that had no wifi capability out of the box. But wouldn't the error message be more 'You havent got any adapter' and not be able to 'see' the wifi network anyway?

Comment: @Fredy31 who knows - but I see now actually in the screenshot that it looks like a more modern 360 that probably doesn't require the adapter.

Comment: Timmy Jim You're correct, I have a more modern 360 that doesn't require the adapter.

Comment: And to your point @Fredy31, yes, all my other devices right next to the 360 have good signals/full bars.

Comment: As a stab in the dark you could try wired temporarily to see if there's any updates that fix it.

Comment: Like option A- Pull a long cable to plug it in for a little while or B- Setup a computer screen in the laundry room, plug the xbox straight in, and wait to see for a few updates. That might fix it.

Comment: Alright, I hooked up the 360 in the laundry room with a computer screen, and it still didn't work. However, when I plugged an ethernet cable into the modem (Again, the modem only picks up a signal in the laundry room.), the 360 immediately connected to my home network. I looked at the IP and DNS settings for the 360 while the ethernet cable was plugged in (I set them to automatic.), and then I disconnected the ethernet cable, entered the IP and DNS settings for the 360 in wireless mode and set the settings to manual (since it doesn't pick up the settings automatically when the 360 is in wirele

Comment: ss mode), and tested the connection again, and it still doesn't work. What now?

Comment: Any more suggestions?

Comment: Any more suggestions?